# Reverse REGEX Based SELECT in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'patterns' that stores the Pattern.

```
ID | Pattern
_______________________________________
1  | Capital of %%India%% is %%Delhi%%
________________________________________
2  | %% Delhi%% is the capital of %%India%%
```

Now I want to find the ID for below string.

"Capital of Maharashtra is Mumbai"

Note: above table may have 1000s of rows with such type of Pattern. Value specified between %% and %% is variable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I created pattern table like this

```
ID | Pattern
_______________________________________
1  | Capital of %%India%% is %%Delhi%%
________________________________________
2  | %% Delhi%% is the capital of %%India%%
________________________________________
3  | Capital of %%%% is %%%%
________________________________________
4  | Capital of %%Maharashtra%% is %%Mumbai%%
```

Run the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM reg_match rm WHERE 'Capital of Maharashtra is Mumbai' LIKE rm.`pattern`;
```

I got this result:

```
ID | Pattern
________________________________________
3  | Capital of %%%% is %%%%
________________________________________
4  | Capital of %%Maharashtra%% is %%Mumbai%%
```

Is this what you are expecting?